# How to setup in superset a Time-Series-line-chart over TIME

Tags: datetime, time-series, apache-superset

I want to create a chart that offers a comparison of several days over day-time.

I tried to build the chart with the following column-data:

- X-axis: time
- Y-axis: value
- Legend: day

My dataset looks like this:

[image: Column data type]

However, it seems that Superset supports only DATETIME. So i can't set the Time column as the X axis in my time series chart.

[image: Chart-Seettings]

What do I need to do to make this happen?

thank you!